# Разная подсветка синтаксиса в зависимости от способа оформления кода

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, подсветка-синтаксиса

Похоже, что на внутристрочный код не распространяется подсветка синтаксиса. Проверка: `$('.Foo > span, .Foo > p').parent()`

Проверка 2:

```
$('.Foo > span, .Foo > p').parent()
```

Замечено вот в этом вопросе: [Как получить с помощью селектора блок, в котором есть определенные элементы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/505773/181472)

Comment: вроде бы так всегда было

Comment: @Nofate, как-то не обращал внимания :)

Comment: This is by design; we only show features like syntax colorization on blocks of text, as per your second example. (=>google translate=>) Это предусмотрено конструкцией ; мы показываем только такие функции, как синтаксис расцвечивания на блоки текста , как на втором примере .

Comment: @MarcGravell thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Перевод [комментария @MarkGravell](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2744/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0#comment8536_2744)

> This is by design; we only show features like syntax colorization on
>   blocks of text, as per your second example.

Так и задумано. Такие фишки, как подсветка кода, работают только на блоках кода.